# Directly read stream from uv4l server on external node.js server in network

Tags: uv4l, webrtc

I'm trying to connect the uv4l-server stream directly to a node.js server.

I'd like to be able to read the stream with the node-webrtc package on an external device. I already have a websocket connection between the two.

I know i can get a stream as an mjpeg by default but I need an actual webRTC stream so i can use it with the node-webrtc package.

What I'm trying to achieve in the end is to recreate the example at https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/blob/master/examples/video-compositing but with a stream from the raspberry pi.

Hope this all makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. If you're working around WebRTC, no need to describe Kurento. It was hard to port packages(they didn't release an ARM version) yourself but you can install it [by this repository](https://github.com/agonza1/kurento-rpi-live-streaming).

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I'm not running docker. also the Package looks like it does need a browser for it to work. I'd like to directly read the video as a stream in node.js